# Unable to add toasts to the group in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, toast

```
ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

// Retrieve the content part of the toast so we can change the text.
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

//Find the text component of the content
XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

// Set the text on the toast. 
// The first line of text in the ToastText02 template is treated as header text, and will be bold.
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(toastHeading));
toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(toastBody));

// Set the duration on the toast
IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

// Create the actual toast object using this toast specification.
ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
toast.group ??????????????????
return toast;
```

If I write `toast.` the group property doesn't appear. With `toast.group` I am getting a red line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using C#, it should be `toast.Group`. Properties and methods are always capitalized.

As for why the group property doesn't appear, maybe Intellisense is just giving out? Mine does that pretty often.